# layer group in Leaflet.markercluster

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am using leaflet and marker-cluster plugin to show data in React. I have two fake layer-groups that I have added them in overlay part of the map. Also two main layer-groups for my different markers in the marker-cluster group. Now I can remove or add main groups in the cluster by checking the overlay check Box with the following code. based on [this](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/458)

```
this.map.on("overlayadd", (e) =>{
  if (e.layer === this.onlineGroup) markersCluster.addLayer(this.onG);
  if (e.layer === this.offlineGroup) markersCluster.addLayer(this.offG);
});
this.map.on("overlayremove", (e) =>{
  if (e.layer === this.onlineGroup) markersCluster.removeLayer(this.onG);
  if (e.layer === this.offlineGroup) markersCluster.removeLayer(this.offG);
});
```

This part is working fine. But when I remove these layers from cluster and update my marker by doing `markers[id].setLatLng([latitude,longitude]);` it appears on the map while its layer is removed from cluster.

Comment: Tangentially related: Is there a particular reason why you are using vanilla leaflet and not react-leaflet in your react application?

Comment: @jbccollins Actually there are more flexibility by using leaflet instead of react-leaflet for my project-at first i used react-leaflet then changed to leaflet. However, this problem is the same in both cases.